# Table View is not reflecting change in size

Tags: swift

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  practise
//
//  Created by ali on 29/11/2019.
//  Copyright © 2019 smartsolution. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class nestedviewcontroller: UIViewController {
    var maindatacells:[String]=["m1","m2","m3","m9"]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


}
extension nestedviewcontroller:UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        return maindatacells.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! maintablecell
        cell.lbltitle.text  = maindatacells[indexPath.row]
        cell.setdata(cont: self)
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        var height = cell.frame.height
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
          var heightjjj = cell.frame.height
    }
}

class maintablecell:UITableViewCell,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{

    @IBOutlet weak var tblheightconstraint:NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var lbltitle:UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tblinside:UITableView!
    var cellheight:CGFloat = 20
    var parentcont:UIViewController!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        tblinside.delegate = self
        tblinside.dataSource = self
    }
    func setdata(cont:UIViewController){
        self.parentcont = cont
    }
    var datacells = ["i1","i2","i3","67"]
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return datacells.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = datacells[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.row == 0{
            cellheight = 0
        }
        cellheight += cell.contentView.frame.height

        if indexPath.row == datacells.count - 1{
          //  var tbl = self.superview as! UITableView
          //  tblinside.estimatedRowHeight = cellheight
          //  tbl.estimatedRowHeight = cellheight
           tblheightconstraint.constant = cellheight
            tblinside.beginUpdates()
            tblinside.endUpdates()
            self.setNeedsDisplay()
            self.setNeedsLayout()
            self.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
            self.parentcont.view.setNeedsLayout()
            self.parentcont.view.setNeedsDisplay()

//            var siz = self.frame.size
//          //
//            self.frame.size = CGSize(width: siz.width, height: siz.height + 30)
        }
    }

}
```

I am updating tableview size programmaticaly by changing its constraint. But tableview is not reflecting the change untill i refresh tableview by scrolling.I have tried many functions to update layout of main cell or tableview but i didnt find anything helping.
The tableview resize perfectly when i scroll the maintableview and the cell freshes

Comment: In which method you are calling these lines?

Comment: i have tried many methods to refresh the layout but didnt find anything helping

Comment: i am actually implementing nested tableview.i want to change size of tableview which is inside the cell of maintableview.

Comment: 'func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)'

Comment: i think you need to call these lines in appear.. su kehvu @Hima?